# Multiple images fill screen width using CSS

Tags: html, css, image, width, screen

I have multiple images to show in a row that filled screen width:

```
<img src="1.jpg" style="max-width:25%">
<img src="2.jpg" style="max-width:25%">
<img src="3.jpg" style="max-width:25%">
<img src="4.jpg" style="max-width:25%">
```

In some pages I have **4** images but some have **5**, **6**, etc.

I don't want to change max-width for every pages so is that a way in CSS to take care of it?

p.s. I don't want to use table and background-image since a js plugin need find them as img, also img tag is google-friendly too...

Comment: just write img { max-width:25%; height:auto; } in your css code.

Comment: As I said, some page I have 5 images, which need max-width:20%, this is not very scalable when I have 100+ similar pages,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pure CSS way to solve it. Little jQuery can do it for you:

```
$(parentElem).each(function() {

    var itemsCount = $(this).children().length;
    var childrenWidth = 100 / itemsCount + '%';

    $(this).children().css('width', childrenWidth);

});
```

where *parentElem* is container for your images. jQuery `each` loop here in case you have multiple rows with images on your page.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It's really useful and can be mastered to make almost any kind of grid you want. Wrap all images in container class with `display:flex` and for each `img` element set `flex:1`. This is the simplest way. If you need to adjust it, read about it, it's great! [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/1qu6qrhj/1/)

```css
.flexContainer {
  display:flex;
  max-height:200px;
  
}
.flexContainer > img {
flex:1;
border:1px solid;
margin:1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-640-480-5.jpg"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/technics-q-c-640-480-10.jpg" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-640-480-3.jpg" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-640-480-5.jpg"/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="flexContainer">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-640-480-5.jpg"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/technics-q-c-640-480-10.jpg" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-640-480-3.jpg" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-640-480-5.jpg"/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/technics-q-c-640-480-10.jpg" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-640-480-3.jpg" />
</div>
```